# How to set default browser in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, browser

The built-in `Settings -> System -> Default apps -> Web browser` menu for setting the default browser in Windows 10 doesn't actually work.

The first few times I tried to change the browser from Edge to Google Chrome, clicking Google Chrome in the menu had no effect.

Now, after several reboots, the menu has no value (blank), and clicking Google Chrome STILL has no effect.

Comment: I had this exact problem. I think it's Cortana that needs to be configured. If you need a browser opened, the default will open. But Cortana always uses Edge. Sad.

Comment: Click `Set defaults by app` which opens the classic Default Programs window. you can set the defaults there.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to reset the defaults in Windows to get it to work.  An alternative for Chrome is actually in the browser itself.

In Chrome:  Menu Hamburger--> Settings -->  Look for Default Browser or browse to chrome://settings/ Look for Default Browser settings.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps:-

Start => Default Programs => Set Default Programs =>  Select Chrome => Select Chrome as Default Browser.

Answer (score -3):

The interns that wrote the Windows 10 *Default app* UI managed to screw up a menu list, in multiple ways.

Workaround: Select another browser, such as Edge, then select the desired browser.

Comment: Your question indicates this does not work, so your answer, is sort of confusing

Comment: Do interns really develop for Microsoft?